# Isolate search results in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm researching methods to isolate queries and results within SharePoint 2013 Search, allowing different data to be searched under different situations. The other caveat being that a user control configuration is unacceptable (as it would allow power users to potentially gain access to data they shouldn't see).

The example case is:
 -General users should be able to search Sharepoint normally except for items of TYPE X
 -Search for critical items of TYPE X must be always be audited and must always run through a separate search form which tracks detailed information
 -Because TYPE X is sensitive customer data, it must never be searchable by any other means

I'm wondering if this can be done via configuration plus a custom search webpart, perhaps using Metadata managed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at creating your own result source, add filter to remove items of Type X and make that as default result source?

Here is the link to TechNet article explaining how to create a Result Source:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Right now I'm researching both this and securitypretrimming to see if there's a way to tailor results that way. The problem I have with Result Source is that it appears to be something that a site collection admin would be able to toggle and thus override/ignore.